# webBrowser1.Navigate ("javascript:__doPostBack('....')"); on C#.NET is not working

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I am working on a C#-based application that navigates to the URL that I want using WebBrowser Control. But when I insert a linklabel1 inside my Form1.cs [Design] and code it to navigate the same as the link label found on the URL I want, which is...

`javascript:__doPostBack('_ctl0$PlaceHolderMain$Loginapp2$lnkforgot','')`

In my coded linklabel1_Click, it is:

`weBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:__doPostBack('_ctl0$PlaceHolderMain$Loginapp2$lnkforgot','')";`

It does nothing at all, the page remains constant, I get no status indicator that the webpage is being navigated. Any suggesstions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("__doPostBack", new object[] { "_ctl0$PlaceHolderMain$Loginapp2$lnkforgot", "" });`

Is this what you want?